# What Type of Caulking will adhere to Composite Decking for water proofing?

Tags: decking, seal, composite

I need a sealer Caulk to fill a approx. 3/8" gap between my Composite Decking boards to waterproof
and prevent water from dripping between the boards and going on to a deck below. I want the rain water to flow over the composite decking boards to the edge of the deck and run off onto a roof that will take the water away.

What is the best product for this application?
What product will adhere to and seal to Composite Decking?

Comment: I would not recommend sealing gaps between deck boards, decks are carefully designed and constructed and those gaps serve an important purpose. The best way to divert water from a deck and prevent it from falling through would be to enclose the upper deck or at least add a roof above it.

Comment: You're [asking the wrong question](http://xyproblem.info). Caulk is not a solution for this--it will look terrible and it will fail in short order. To provide solutions we need more information about your deck. Photos would be great.

Comment: You have a deck below a deck? Why not just waterproof both decks, which I imagine is mostly done for you if you're using composite decking materials?

Answer (score 4):

Typically you need those gaps for expansion of the boards in hot weather- if they're tight to each other they can get damaged as they expand from heat.

They make under-deck panels that catch the water and direct it out a side that work very well. That would be a better solution than caulking, which would most likely need to be re-done every year or two anyway.